# $ positional update operator with upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

Say I have a collection of shops:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "items": [
      {"_id": 3, "price": 10}
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "_id": 2
  }
]
```

I want to update the `price` of item 3 in a shop to 30, inserting a new item in the shop if no item exists in that shop and/or inserting a new shop if necessary:

- shop 0: simply updates the item
- shop 1: appends `{"_id": 3, "price": 30}` to shop 1's `items`
- shop 2: sets shop 2's `items` to `[{"_id": 3, "price": 30}]`
- shop 3: inserts the document `{"_id": 3, "items": [{"_id": 3, "price": 30}]}`

In other terms, I want to:

- `collection.updateOne({_id: <shopId>, 'items._id': 3}, {$set: {'items.$.price': 30}})` if the item exists (shop 0)
- `collection.updateOne({_id: <shopId>}, {$push: {items: {_id: 3, price: 30}}}, {upsert: true})` if it doesn't (shops 1 to 3)

This is kind of like `$` with `upsert`, but [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#upsert) clearly states that `upsert` cannot be used with it:

> Do not use the positional operator `$` with upsert operations because inserts will use the `$` as a field name in the inserted document.

[`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#upsert) doesn't work either:

> If the upsert operation did not include an exact equality match and no matching documents were found to update, the upsert operation would error.

Is there a way to do this without having to hit the database multiple times?

---

Things I've tried:

```js
// Updating the path 'items' would create a conflict at 'items'
collection.updateOne(
  {_id: 0, 'items._id': 3},
  {$set: {'items.$.price': 30}, $setOnInsert: {items: []}}
)

// $[<identifier>] with upsert doesn't work
// The path 'items' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.
collection.updateOne(
  {_id: 2},
  {$set: {'items.$[item].price': 30}},
  {arrayFilters: [{'item._id': 3}], upsert: true}
)

// Updating the path 'items' would create a conflict at 'items'
collection.updateOne(
  {_id: 0},
  {$set: {'items.$[item].price': 30}, $setOnInsert: {items: []}},
  {arrayFilters: [{'item._id': 3}], upsert: true}
)
```

Comment: If you have all those variations in the database, what is wrong with using two queries? Use bulk write to send them together.

Comment: @D.SM I'm a beginner in mongodb, so I didn't know about `bulkWrite`. Maybe you should put that in an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [D. SM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540925/d-sm) said, you can use [`bulkWrite`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) to do multiple operations in one go:

```js
const shopId = 0
collection.bulkWrite([
  // Remove any existing item
  {
    updateOne: {
      filter: {_id: shopId},
      update: {$pull: {items: {_id: 3}}}
    }
  },
  // Add the item with the updated price to the shop
  {
    updateOne: {
      filter: {_id: shopId},
      update: {
        $push: {items: {_id: 3, price: 30}}
      },
      upsert: true
    }
  }
])
```